# Finding meeting point of discreet functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

[added context per advised]

Hi, I am self-studying number theory, using text of [aata, Beezer, 14](http://abstract.ups.edu/sage-aata.html) and [elementary number theory, Pan, 91](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/7301060750). So far I have finished group theory but not yet ring and field. I encountered exercise as below in [2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/7301060750) (pg 261.) Appreciate explanation that utilize group theory. Thanks.

[rewording per required]

I have a sum of arithmetic series $n(1+n)/2$, and a linear function $nk$.

If I want to find the meeting point of their sum with $2^m$.

Is there a way better than brutal force try n error?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you ever considered this equation geometrically?

Comment: @robit Considering now. So, let y=RHS, then the y-n plane is parabola, while the y-k plane is a line. But I don't see how it help, since we consider discrete func.

Comment: I mean RHS can be perceived as a triangle concatenated with a rectangle :D

Comment: @modeller: how did this problem arise?

Comment: @robjohn one exercise in number theory text.

Comment: If you mentioned this, perhaps with some details (what book, etc), in the question, it would provide some context and perhaps get the question re-opened.

Comment: @modeller: Rewording is not really the problem, I think. I think those who closed the question are looking for some context: what class this is for, what background you are expected to have, etc. so that those who answer know where to start and how to better focus their answers.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for the advice. Yes I agree that context will help understanding. I suspect the 2nd series is related to ring but I had not covered yet.

Comment: @modeller: that looks good. Now let's hope people vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can factor out n:

$2^m=n\cdot \left( \frac{1+n}{2}+k \right)$

n has to be a faktor of $2^m$. Let it be $2^p$.

$2^m=2^p\cdot \left( \frac{1+2^p}{2}+k \right)$

multiplying the equation by 2.

$2^{m+1}=2^p\cdot \left(1+2^p+2k \right)$

The equation does not hold, because $1+2^p+2k$ is an odd number.

*Referring to the comment of robjohn:*

If $2^p=1$ and $k=2^m-1$  the equation becomes $2^{m+1}=1\cdot \left(1+1+2^{m+1}-2 \right)$ The equation holds in this case.

Comment: Unless $n=1$ and $k=2^m-1$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks. It seems with this proposition, now the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: @robjohn You are right. I have made an edit. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{n(1+n)}{2}+nk=n\left(\frac{n+1}{2}+k\right)
$$
so if this has to hold $n$ has to be a factor of $2^m$.

For any $n\leq2^{\frac{m}{2}}$ it is easy to find values of $k$ that solves the equation.

Comment: this only works if $n=1$